# Mouse and keyboard freeze Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, mouse, freeze

Hopefully, someone explain me how to fix it. Every single day I have the same issue. While working on pc (I recently updated my os to Ubuntu 20.04) my USB mouse (not wired) and keyboard) freeze. I cannot use keyboard, it is not answering and mouse cursor is not moving. After I restart it manually (by pressing power/reset button) everything is working again fine till the next freeze (usually 1-2 times a day).  I did not have any problems on previous version on Ubuntu. Please help me. Thank you in advance for all replies.

```
Processor AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor

{# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=9282d35e-95fe-4d4b-93de-f80a4b1e0a3c none            swap    sw              0       0}

{Filename               Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition   16706556    0   -2}
```

UPDATED
dmesg https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cyFrK8VKFr/
journalctl https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nssc8rdCzt/

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114024/discussion-on-question-by-helen-mouse-and-keyboard-freeze-ubuntu-20-08) - please continue there if needed.

Comment: @heynnema Also had bad internet bandwidth after updating Ubuntu on OSB program (usually it is very good), so I simply reinstalled OBS and everything worked well. So I do the same with browser - maybe it will help. Who knows.

Comment: @heynnema no reply from Asrock support  yet, unfortunately.  OBS - is soft for streaming, when I tried to stream usually the signal is green but after installation ubuntu 20.04 it was red.

Comment: @heynnema I decieded to reinstall my browser because mouse and keyboard freeze usually when I am surfing in internet

Comment: @heynnema freeze also appeared when I was using viber, did a memtest for 1 Gb - everything ok, will do full test tom morning

Comment: Good job! Remember to use the chat to continue our dialog. Keep using @heynnema there too, so I get notified of your updates. Cheers!

Comment: @heynnema checked memtest (I had to enter 15 Gb) because when I tried to enter in terminal 16000M it kills the process. For current 15Gb everything is ok, checked twice via command "sudo memtester 15000M 2"

Comment: @heynnema can you please look at hardware errors here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9nhbGpcMCQ/     What do you think?

Comment: @heynnema plz check this - maybe I can do smth similar? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245608

Comment: Please see my comments in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114024/discussion-on-question-by-helen-mouse-and-keyboard-freeze-ubuntu-20-08). We really need to stay there.

Comment: @helen Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Hi heynnemma sorry for kept you waiting. I managed to fix this issue. And I will close as solved. Please save the answer. I read that after changing setting in bios - pc may have some problems like freezing. So I just reset Bios to default using following commands: sudo modprobe nvram
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram

Comment: @helen  Oh, that method sounds kind of dangerous. Where did you find that info? Did you ever hear back from ASUS Support regarding the proper BIOS for your processor? Is 2.30 or 3.30 or 4.00 the correct one to use?

Comment: @heynnema well, maybe, but i did not have other choice. I revived in memory the chain of changes that I applied to pc (from the moment it stopped working) and come to the point (like you said) it is BIOS issue. Unfortunately ASRock support not answered to my question. My main mistake was to insert HDD drive with working Ubuntu on it. I had to clean it first and then allow to insert that I did not do.  I have also a question to you - how to close this question. I did not find any button here) Thank you for help, I really appreciate your time spending with me and my problem. Warm wishes, Helen

Comment: @helen You're quite welcome! I'd recommend **calling** ASRock Support, to really determine which BIOS is correct for your processor. My answer is still correct, esp if you have the incorrect BIOS installed. That's why the reset probably worked.

Comment: @helen To close the question, you click on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of the accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question... Freeze may appear because of changes in BIOS. I had to reset settings of BIOS to default and PC actually stopped freezing. Commands I used:

```
sudo modprobe nvram 
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram
```

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

ASRock A320M-HDV R4.0

You have BIOS version 3.30, from 8/6/2019.

This **MAY** be the wrong BIOS when used with a Summit Ridge processor (AMD Ryzen 3 1200). Contact ASRock Support for confirmation. See the [CPU Support List](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/a320m-hdv%20r4.0/index.asp#CPU).

BIOS 2.30 was the last BIOS that supported this processor. See [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/a320m-hdv%20r4.0/index.asp#BIOS).

The newest BIOS is version 4.00, dated 7/29/2020... but again, it may not be appropriate for your processor. See [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/a320m-hdv%20r4.0/index.asp#BIOS).

**memtest**

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Thank you heynnema, I will contact then asap and write you here, also sometimes when I want to power off pc  it is not shutting down (bu t I receiver a black screen with lower case

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to move the wireless dongle away from the USB port of the machine to a port in the display (the display is connected to the machine also via a USB cable).

I guess, some processes in the machine created an em field that interfered with the wireless signal and occasionally interrupted the connection between the keyboard/mouse and the machine.