# Extenal USB keyboard freezes

Tags: usb, thinkpad, amd-ryzen

I have a problem a bit similar to the one described here: [Mouse and keyboard freeze Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280853/mouse-and-keyboard-freeze-ubuntu-20-04)

My machine:

```
Thinkpad T14
Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 4750U with Radeon Graphics
Ubuntu 20.10
Kernel: 5.9.3-050903-generic 

Bios: 
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.
```

A few times a day my external keyboard freezes for a few seconds. I tried to debug the problem by following tips from the question mentioned above and see in the `dmesg` logs that the keyboard gets actually disconnected and reconnected, sometimes it happens a few times in a row:

```
[23005.886648] usb 6-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 14
[23006.367659] usb 6-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[23006.489772] usb 6-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=6047, bcdDevice= 3.30
[23006.489775] usb 6-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[23006.489777] usb 6-2.2: Product: ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint
[23006.489778] usb 6-2.2: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[23006.564154] input: Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-2/6-2.2/6-2.2:1.0/0003:17EF:6047.0014/input/input40
[23006.624059] lenovo 0003:17EF:6047.0014: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint] on usb-0000:07:00.4-2.2/input0
[23006.631327] input: Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:07:00.4/usb6/6-2/6-2.2/6-2.2:1.1/0003:17EF:6047.0015/input/input41
[23006.688075] lenovo 0003:17EF:6047.0015: input,hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Lenovo ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint] on usb-0000:07:00.4-2.2/input1
[23006.910603] usb 6-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 15
```

The full `dmesg` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G6cVfh9Htg/

I haven't noticed any pattern when this happens - sometimes after a few minutes of keyboard inactivity, sometimes in the middle of writing a sentence.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Is the keyboard wireless or wired?

Comment: It's a wired Lenovo KU-1255 keyboard, I'm pretty sure that it works flawlessly.

Comment: And you have tried other keyboards to be sure ?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't. I have another wired keyboard, will try.